# Check if list is ordered

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to compare the elements of a `list` of `integer` to see if they are ordered (or not). I'm using `Amzi!`

I gave a few attempts, but nothing works... :(

```
ordered([X]).
ordered([N|[N1|L]]) :- N <= N1, ordered([N1|L]).

ordered_([X]).
ordered_([Head,Head1|Tail]) :- Head <= Head1, ordered_([Head1|Tail]).
```

Both return `no` if this list is entered:

```
ordered([1,2,3,4]).
ordered_([1,2,3,4]).
```

I understand that I need to compare the `head` with the `head of the tail`.

Comment: a typo: <= should be =<

Comment: Check out if `<=` is a defined operator! With SWI-Prolog I got `?- 1 <= 2.
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: 1
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  <= 2 .`

Comment: @CapelliC and @repeat, you guys are right, I was testing with `=<` but changed to `<=` to see if that was the problem. I forgot to return to the correct one.

Comment: @NickeManarin. Alright! Out of curiosity: did you get a syntax error with `<=` or is that an AMZI Prolog operator/predicate with another meaning than "arithmetic comparison"? (Perhaps something like boolean implication?)

Comment: No, it was a simple mistake... I should save and reconsult the listener after changing to `<=`. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't seem like it should be any more complex than

```
ordered( []      ) .
ordered( [_]     ) .
ordered( [X,Y|Z] ) :- X =< Y , ordered( [Y|Z] ) .
```

Arithmetic comparison predicates are covered here: http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_math.htm#MathematicalComparisons

Use `@=</2` or `compare/3` to check the ordering of things in the *standard order of terms*: http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_manipulating_terms.htm#StandardOrder

Answer (score 2):

a compact alternative:

```
ordered(L) :- \+ ( append(_,[A,B|_], L), A > B ).
```

Comment: Unexpected creative approach. Thanks for additional exercise for my brain.

Comment: `ordered(non_list)` succeeds

Answer (score 0):

More efficient alternative to most upvoted solution, comparing three instead of appending the bigger element back to the list

```
is_sorted([]).
is_sorted([X, Y, Z|T]) :- X =< Y, Y =< Z, is_sorted(T).
is_sorted([X, Y|T]) :- X =< Y, is_sorted(T).
```

Comment: Incorrectly succeeds for `is_sorted([8,9,2,3]).` It is also less efficient, as `is_sorted([1,2,3,4,5]).` succeeds twice.